# Getting stream Closed in spring controller + angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring

I want to save my textbox details into master table and table details into sub table. when i do it separately it works fine.. but when i done it same time it gave an error as stream closed.. Then how will i resolve this.. please help me..

My js part

```
$scope.savePurchaseOrder = function(supid,po) {
        $scope.lastAction = 'savePurchaseOrder';
        var url = $scope.url + supid ;
        $http.post(url,po,$scope.rows).success(function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            alert("PurchaseOrder Saved  Successfully!!")
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.handleErrorInDialogs(status);
        });

    };
```

My Spring Controller

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/{supid}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces     
= "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String savePurchaseOrder(
        @PathVariable("supid") Integer supid,
        @RequestBody MasterPurchaseOrder masterpurchaseorder,
        @RequestBody String suborder) throws Exception {


    return "Saved Successfully!!";

}
```

Demo 
http://plnkr.co/edit/iip3u8BrXgWi0is60iFq?p=preview

Comment: Hey, do you expect somebody here to debug all that code ? Please reduce to a minimal working example showing the exact problem.

Comment: hey no sir,i put all code because i dont want to trouble you.. Am sorry sir.. i want to pass my textbox values and html table values into spring controller.. when i pass , it make an error stream closed.can you please tell me what changes i want to make in jsp page & spring controller

Comment: improved html formatting

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thank you sir... now i edited my code.could you please check the above code??

Comment: i got answer... thank you all for your previous time and help.. i edited my js page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.savePurchaseEntry = function(supid, poid) {

        $scope.lastAction = 'savePurchaseEntry';
        var url = $scope.url + supid + "/" + poid;
          var item  = ($scope.po).concat($scope.pe);
        console.log(pe.balance);
        $http.post(url,item).success(function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            alert("PurchaseDetails Saved  Successfully!!")
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.handleErrorInDialogs(status);
        });

    };
```